# How do you add your custom emoji in discord.js code?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Whenever i run my code i get this error

(node:552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Emoji.

Im trying to add my own emojis but thats not working and im a beginner to discord.js
This is my first time actually working with reactionroles so i have no idea how to use them. Using normal emojis work but i want to use my custom emojis

Heres my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Color } = require("../../config.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        let FortniteEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("879625063643635713");
        let ApexEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("879624843920809985");
        const channel = '869871201621790741';
        const RavineaRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Fortnite Tryouts");
        const YouAgainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Apex Legends Tryouts");
 
        const RavineaEmoji = `FortniteEmoji`;
        const YouAgainEmoji = `ApexEmoji`;
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Tryout For The Following Games!')
            .setDescription('Enter The Tryouts!\n\n'
                + `${RavineaEmoji} for Fortnite\n`
                + `${YouAgainEmoji} for Apex Legends`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(RavineaEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(YouAgainEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RavineaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RavineaRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === YouAgainEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(YouAgainRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RavineaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RavineaRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === YouAgainEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(YouAgainRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't put events inside of a command file like that, make a separate file for them

Answer (score 0):

It appears as you've defined the emojis as strings, therefore you are trying to react to a message with a string, which won't work.

Solution:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Color } = require("../../config.js");
module.exports = {
    name: 'reactionrole',
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        let FortniteEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("879625063643635713");
        let ApexEmoji = client.emojis.cache.get("879624843920809985");
        const channel = '869871201621790741';
        const RavineaRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Fortnite Tryouts");
        const YouAgainRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Apex Legends Tryouts");
 
        const RavineaEmoji = FortniteEmoji;
        const YouAgainEmoji = ApexEmoji;
 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Tryout For The Following Games!')
            .setDescription('Enter The Tryouts!\n\n'
                + `${RavineaEmoji} for Fortnite\n`
                + `${YouAgainEmoji} for Apex Legends`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(RavineaEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(YouAgainEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RavineaEmoji)
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RavineaRole);
                if (reaction.emoji.name === YouAgainEmoji)
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(YouAgainRole);
            } else
                return;
        });
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RavineaEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RavineaRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === YouAgainEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(YouAgainRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @MercuryDaGod In that case, the emoji ID's are incorrect.